# Can I cap a local collection in meteor js

Tags: meteor

I want to use a local (un-backed) mongo collection as a cache, but I need to cap it so that it doesn't explode in size. Does anyone know of a good way to do this?

e.g.

```
Cache._createCappedCollection(1024 * 1024 * 10); // 10MB
```

The above works if we're working with a mongo collection, but if the collection is unbacked, then it'll throw an error: `Error("Can only call _createCappedCollection on server collections")`